# Creating comma-separated string from list

Tags: python, string, list, join

I have a list of ints and want to create a comma-separated string. The following:

```
x = [3, 1, 4, 1, 5]
y = ",".join(x)
```

Give the error:

```
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, int found
```

How do I create the string? I could manually convert every element from int to string, insert this into a new list, and then do the join on this new list, but I'm wondering if there is a cleaner solution.

Comment: You could use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map): `y = ",".join(map(str, x))`.

Comment: the `str.join` answer is OK if your list is guaranteed to have only integers - for anything serious use the csv module, it will handle a lot of corner cases.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`str.join` only accepts an iterable of strings, not one of integers.  From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

> `str.join(iterable)`
>
> Return a string which is the concatenation of the **strings** in the iterable `iterable`.

Thus, you need to convert the items in `x` into strings.  You can use either [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) or a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
x = [3, 1, 4, 1, 5]
y = ",".join(map(str, x))

x = [3, 1, 4, 1, 5]
y = ",".join([str(item) for item in x])
```

See a demonstration below:

```
>>> x = [3, 1, 4, 1, 5]
>>>
>>> ",".join(map(str, x))
'3,1,4,1,5'
>>>
>>> ",".join([str(item) for item in x])
'3,1,4,1,5'
>>>
```

Comment: @IoannisFilippidis - Using a list comprehension is more efficient with `str.join`. See here for details: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9061024/2555451

Comment: Very interesting, thank you for noting this. I think it would make a valuable addition to the answer.

Answer (score 4):

If you are dealing with a csv file that is something other than the trivial example here, please do remember you are better off using the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) to read and write csv, since [CSV can be surprisingly complex](http://creativyst.com/Doc/Articles/CSV/CSV01.htm#FileFormat).

Here is a write example:

```
import csv

x = [['Header\n1', 'H 2', 'H 3', 'H, 4'],[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]]

with open('/tmp/test.csv', 'w') as fout:
    writer=csv.writer(fout)
    for l in x:
        writer.writerow(l)
```

Note the embedded comma in `'H, 4'` and the embedded new line in `'Header\n1'` that may trip up efforts to decode if not properly encoded.

The file 'test.csv' that the csv module produces:

```
"Header
1",H 2,H 3,"H, 4"
1,2,3,4
5,6,7,8
9,10,11,12
```

Note the quoting around `"Header\n1"` and "H, 4"` in the file so that the csv is correctly decoded in the future.

Now check you can read that back:

```
with open('/tmp/test.csv') as f:
    csv_in=[[int(e) if e.isdigit() else e for e in row] 
               for row in csv.reader(f)]

>>> csv_in==x
True
```

Just sayin' You are usually better off using the tools in the library for csv.

Answer (score 2):

Just modify the argument to `join` so that each element is converted to a string:

```
x = [3, 1, 4, 1, 5]
y = ",".join(str(i) for i in x)
```